# Python unintended MRO in multiple inheritance

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, inheritance, django-rest-framework

I have the following class design for my viewsets and mixins. My problem is that when I call `super().create()` from `SomeModelViewSet`, it calls that viewset's overridden `update()` instead of the `update()` of `MixinA`. Is calling `MixinA.create(self)` the way to go?

Please do alert me if this is bad design.

*Disclaimer: Me calling `update()` from `create()` is due to a workaround for some uncommon spec*

**mixins.py**

```
class MixinA(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    def create(self, request, *args, left=None, right=None **kwargs):
        # ...
        self.update(request, left=left, right=right)

    def update(self, request, *args, left=None, right=None, **kwargs):
        # ...

class MixinB(mixins.DestroyModelMixin):
    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...

class MixinC(mixins.ListModelMixin):
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs)
        # ...
```

**viewsets.py**

```
class BaseViewSet(MixinC):
    # ...

class MyViewSet(MixinA, MixinB, BaseViewSet):
    pass
```

**views.py**

```
class SomeModelViewSet(MyViewSet):
    def create(self, request, pk=None, **kwargs):
        a = someObj(pk=pk)
        b = someObj(pk=None)
        return super().create(request, left = a, left = b, **kwargs)

    def update(self, request, first_pk=None, second_pk=None, **kwargs):
        a = someObj(pk=first_pk)
        b = someObj(pk=second_pk)
        return super().update(request, left=a, right=b)

    def destroy(self, request, first_pk=None, second_pk=None, **kwargs):
        lookup = {'first__pk': first_pk, 'second_pk': second_pk}
        return super().destroy(request, **lookup)
```

---

> **EDIT**

The MRO appears to be like this

```
SomeModelViewSet.create() -> MixinA.create() -> SomeModelViewSet.update() -> MixinA.update()
```

What I want is this below, thus the `self.update()` in `MixinA.create()`

```
SomeModelViewSet.create() -> MixinA.create() -> MixinA.update()
```

The parameters `left` and `right` change between `MixinA.create()` and `SomeModelViewSet.update()`

```
create(): TripDispatcherViewSet
    # left: Klass(pk='1')
    # right: Klass(pk=None)
create(): IntermediaryModelCreateModelMixin
    # left: Klass(pk='1')
    # right: Klass(pk=None)
update(): TripDispatcherViewSet
    # left: Klass(pk=None)
    # right: Klass(pk=None)
update(): IntermediaryModelCreateModelMixin
    #left: Klass(pk=None)
    # right: Klass(pk=None)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of calls makes sense. When you call `self.update()` you're asking the interpreter to find you the appropriate `update()` method on the `self` object, which is done according to the MRO and therefore finds `SomeModelViewSet.update()`. The fact that you're calling that from inside a method of the `MixinA` class isn't relevant.

So yes, you could get around that by calling `MixinA.update(self)`. However the fundamental issue here is that you're calling an API that was designed for inheritance without actually wanting the inherited behavior. So a better design, in my opinion, is to acknowledge that explicitly by using a different method. Something like:

```
class MixinA(mixins.CreateModelMixin, mixins.UpdateModelMixin):
    def create(self, ...):
        ...
        self._my_update(...)

    def update(self, ...):
        self._my_update(...)

    def _my_update(self, ...):
        ...
```

The advantage here is that you're separating out the API for `update()`—which is designed for inheritance—from the implementation details that you want to harness for `MixinA.create()`.